# Radeon 5600 - 4th screen with low resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, display-resolution, radeon

I have 4 monitors connected to a Radeon 5600XT on Ubuntu 22.04 using the latest amdgpu driver from the vendor's website.

Three monitors are detected properly and work with a high resolution - the 4th one only offers 640x480:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 connected 640x480+1920+600 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       59.94* 
DisplayPort-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.99    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

The two screens connected to the display ports are identical and if I switch the monitors to different ports the other monitor is restricted in it's resolution - so it seems to be an issue with the software or the card - not the monitor itself.

Would appreciate any ideas or help for troubleshooting.